# Multi TCP socket connections does't work on 4.0.4 Android

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I am working on project where i need two or more socket connection at once. I noticed that until android 4.x my app worked correctly, and on android 4.0.4 it just do nothing on second connection. I made simple project to be sure it like that, and in earlier versions two connections is OK, at 4.0.4 it just do nothing, no error, no exception, no log message....

How can i connect two socket at one time in android 4.0.4

**My test server**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket socket1 = new ServerSocket(9045);
    ServerSocket socket2 = new ServerSocket(9046);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    Listener th1 = new Listener(socket1, "||");
    Listener th2 = new Listener(socket2, "==");

    System.out.println("Starting....");

    new Thread(th1).start();
    new Thread(th2).start();
    while (true){
        if (br.readLine().endsWith("exit"))
            break;
    }
    th1.stop();
    th2.stop();

    socket1.close();
    socket2.close();
}

}

class Listener implements Runnable{

int i = 1;
boolean isRunning = true;
ServerSocket socket;
String tag;

public Listener(ServerSocket socket1, String tag) {
    socket = socket1;
    this.tag = tag;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(tag + " started");
    while (isRunning){
        try {
            socket.accept();
            System.out.println(tag + " accepted " + i++);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void stop() {
    isRunning = false;
}

}
```

**Android project**

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Start 1"
            android:onClick="clickStart1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Start 2"
            android:onClick="clickStart2" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.twosocketsapk;

    import com.example.twosocketsapk.SocketClientTask.SocketListener;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SocketListener{

        SocketClientTask task1;
        SocketClientTask task2;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            task1 = new SocketClientTask(this, "192.168.0.21", 9045);
            task2 = new SocketClientTask(this, "192.168.0.21", 9046);

        }

        public void clickStart1(View v) {
            if (task1.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
                task1.execute();
        }

        public void clickStart2(View v) {
            if (task2.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
                task2.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnect(String message) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGetMessage(String message) {

        }

    }
```

SocketClientTask.java

```
package com.example.twosocketsapk;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class SocketClientTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private static final String TAG = SocketClientTask.class.getSimpleName();
        private SocketListener messageHandler;

        private Socket socket = null;
        private PrintWriter socketOut = null;
        private BufferedReader socketIn = null;

        private Boolean isConnected = false;

        String  ip;
        int     port;

        private boolean isRunning = true;

        public SocketClientTask(SocketListener messageHandler, String ip, int port) {
            this.messageHandler = messageHandler;
            this.ip = ip;
            this.port = port;
        }

        public Boolean isConnected() {
            return isConnected;
        }

        public void runReading() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            socketOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            socketIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            isConnected = true;
            while (isRunning) {
                publishProgress(socketIn.readLine());
            }
            socketOut.close();
            socketIn.close();
            socket.close();
        }

        public boolean sendMessage(String line) {
            if (socketOut != null && !socketOut.checkError()) {
                socketOut.println(line);
                socketOut.flush();
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "message: " + line + "; wasn't sent");
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                runReading();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                isConnected = false;
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Client ERROR", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                isConnected = false;
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Client ERROR", e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            messageHandler.onGetMessage(values[0]);
        }

        public void stop() {
            isRunning = false;
        }

        // --

        public interface SocketListener {
            void onConnect(String message);
            void onGetMessage(String message);
        }

    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.twosocketsapk"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.twosocketsapk.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

P.S. Sorry for my English, it isn't my native language

Answer (score 0):

If there is really no exception you are reading lines but you aren't sending lines.

readLine() can return null, which you aren't checking for.

Comment: Thanks, but problem is not there, my test server does not accept any client in second connected socket. Lets say, first I connect to socket1 then when I trying to connect second it just do nothing in android 4.0.4. You can try this in emulator.

Comment: As I said, you are reading lines but you aren't sending them. Your server code does no I/O of any kind, so of course your readLine() blocks. And as there are no exceptions, you don't have any evidence to suggest it doesn't accept a second client.

Comment: I judging by thees lines: 

    socket.accept();
    System.out.println(tag + " accepted " + i++);

if my socket server does not accept client - there is no connection.
And, why then this code works on lower android version

Comment: When your first task blocks waiting for input that is never sent, why are you surprised that the second task never executes? Why don't you *fix your server* so it does something useful, and then re-test?

Comment: I surprised because, they are running in different threads and they should run in the same time. And both tasks status are running after pressing both buttons......... And then, I make client based on Thread, not on AsyncTask, and it worked. So I think in android 4.0.4 there can be running one doInBackground method at the time...